# Radius of convergence and sum of series $3nz^{n-1}$

Tags: calculus

I'm learning complex series and I have a doubt.

I have to find the radius of convergence and the sum of $$\sum_{2}^{\infty} 3nz^{n-1}$$

For $z=0$ I believe the series converges and the sum is $0$.

For $z\neq0$ I've tried to apply the ratio test but with no success.
This is what I have done.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|3n\frac{z^n}{z}|}\Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} |z|\sqrt[n]{\frac{3n}{z}} $$

Getting here I've realized that I've must have done something wrong.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Ideas for finding the sum can be found in  [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn) and the posts in its "related" section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the quotient test (many times more gentle than the $\,n$-th root one):

$$\left|\;\frac{3(n+1)z^n}{3nz^{n-1}}\;\right|=\frac{n+1}n|z|\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}|z|<1$$

Comment: Thanks. Forgot to use that test :( And if $|z|<1$ what would be the radius of convergence? Before making any tests can I assume if $z=0$ that the series is convergent?

Answer (score 0):

It will be nth root of $(3n)$

So the radius of convergence will be $1$ as $n^{1/n}\to 1$  and $3^{1/n}\to 1$as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks. But where did the z's go?

Comment: You can denote $y_{i}=x_{i+1}$ ana then apply root test to $\{y_i\}$